# All random variables following a distributional equation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

How to find out all random variables $X$ satisfying the following 2 conditions:

1. $E(X^2)<\infty$
2. $X$ follows the distributional equation : $X\stackrel{d}{=}{X+Y\over \sqrt2}$ for any random varibale $Y$ independent of $X$ such that $Y\stackrel{d}{=}X$

I am not getting where to begin with.

EDIT :

> Any $X$ following $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ will hold true, since $X^2$ will follow $\chi^2$ distribution which has finite mean.

Edit $2$: $\mu=0$ by the second equation. So $N(0,\sigma^2)$ is one candidate.

So still the question remains. Is this the only one? is there any general way to characterize all of them?

Comment: @NP-hard I think thats what the question meant.

Comment: +1) I only come up with Gaussian as an example, since it is 2-stable.

Comment: @MichaelHardy $\infty>\sigma^2>0$

Comment: TYPO: I meant of course $\sigma^2<\infty. \qquad$

Comment: I've see the notation $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ used ONLY when it is assumed that $\sigma^2<\infty$, so $\operatorname{E}(X^2) = \mu^2 + \sigma^2 < \infty,$ so your remark about $chi^2$ doesn't seem to be needed.$\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $X$ satisfies 1. and 2. Let $\left(Y_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ be an i.i.d. sequence distributed as $X$. Then $\mathbb E\left[X\right]= 2\sqrt 2\mathbb E\left[X\right]$, hence $X$ is centered. Now, we can show by induction on $n$ that 
$$\frac 1{2^{n/2}}\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}Y_i \overset{d}{=}  X ,$$
hence by the central limit theorem, $X$ is normally distributed.